# A good estimate as to how many visitors are bots

Tags: google-analytics, bots

My blog is about 7 months old. At my current level I usually get around 100 sessions per day. I have always actively filtered out all ghost referrers as they appear and thus should have virtually none of them appearing in my Google Analytics data. I have also checked the box that instructs Analytics to ignore "known bots".

So I'm wondering after all these measures, how many of my sessions each day should I still reasonably chalk up to bot traffic?

And a side question, is there anything else I can do to make my Analytics data more accurate in detecting only real human traffic?

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is add an invisible link to you main page anyone clicking on the link has a very high probability of being a bot.

Comment: Good tip, thanks. I'm hoping someone has some general statistics too though.